# Is really NMAP uses ping packets to consider Host discovery?

Tags: port, arp, nmap, scanning, icmp

I run this command  `nmap -sn 192.168.0.2` for only Host discovery. And then I started wireshark to see what will going to happen.

I thought It would send ICMP echo req, but the results was very different.

It uses ARP protocol not ICMP. Even I didn't see any single entry of ICMP in wireshark.

Why It uses ARP protocol? And How it determine that its open or not? Am I missing any thing?

See the results.

[image: Image of wireshark results]

[Wireshark Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTyrq.png)

**EDIT: I uses TCP dump and get the results to .cap file and then run it through wireshark.**

Comment: What did your actual nmap output look like? Those ARP requests could also be caused by other processes running. All in all it looks pretty incomplete. As for what should be happening have a look at the [documentation](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html).

Comment: I saw this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31854/what-does-pn-option-mean-in-nmap/31855

Comment: And see the last comment at the answer.

Comment: Btw, Nmap shows that the host is Up.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html):

> Also note that ARP/Neighbor Discovery (-PR) is done by default against targets on a local ethernet network even if you specify other -P* options, because it is almost always faster and more effective.

And more specifically for `-sn`:

> When a privileged user tries to scan targets on a local ethernet network, ARP requests are used unless --send-ip was specified.

In your screenshot your terminal is using root credentials.

Comment: I have added a new pic. Please see that. And sorry about the Link, I can't embed that because of ponits.

Comment: I don't know what you want to prove by adding the second screenshot. You're running a completely different command. You claim you did use wireshark to do the capture now you're using tcpdump (without including information about how you use it). It's still unclear what machine is running what and which IPs are being used by those machines. Your second screenshot also includes the expected SYN for `-sS`. This answer focuses on `-sn` and as the documentation states it will use ARP - if run from a privileged account unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Whenever it would be the same would depends on whenever you applied filters to tcpdump or not. As you are on the same network there is no reason to discover a host if you only want to scan it. Naturally you will see ARP regardless as you need that information for your communication. ICMP is not necessary to establish a connection. DIscovery and Scan are also very different things as the first is usually done for a range while the last only targets a particular host.